# Calculate % from two tables using sub-querys

Tags: mysql, pentaho, percentage, report-designer

It's a simple query that pulls data, counts the number of results and displays that total for the user. I am using sub-queries and pulling from two different tables for these results.

> select count(trans_station),     trans_station from cuesheet_tx_dates
>   where trans_station = "his"  and txdate between "15-01-01" and
>   "15-01-31"

^This returns all data within the date and channel code

> SELECT count(*) as HISr  FROM cuesheet_tx_dates td INNER JOIN
>        cuesheets s
>        ON td.cuesheets_id = s.id WHERE td.txdate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31' AND 
>         td.trans_station = 'his' AND
>         s.status = 'C';

^This returns all **completed** data within the date and channel code

I need to know how to calculate the percentage of completed data against all data. I am using Pentaho Report Designer CE, mysql db.

Comment: show you db table structure as well, and elaborate more **completed data against all data**?

Comment: I am using a 3rd party program to pull from the database. i don't have access to the table structure. 

All data is basically pulling all rows with channel code "his" between 1st - 31st of Jan. The completed data is linked to a second table, it uses the status row from the second table to identify additional data within the same date that is not in the cuesheets table

Comment: Do you use a ktr for this? or direct JDBC connections?

Comment: direct jdbc connection

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula to get the result of a query using "singlevaluequery" function. For example, let's say we create a formula called "transStationAmountFormula". The content of the formula should be:

```
=SINGLEVALUEQUERY("query_to_get_amount_of_trans_stations")
```

Following the same pattern, you can create as much formulas (and other queries) to get the numbers you need to make calculations.

Hope it helps.